# Suspension vector direction of a raycast vehicle

Tags: physics, vector, transformation, car, vehicle

I'm working on a raycast-based vehicle in a 3D world using a physics engine. It's basically a chassis object that contains a transform (translation, rotation, scale), a dynamic rigid body (with mass, center of mass and other stuff from the physics engine) and 4 wheel children.
Each wheel has its own transform, positioned where the vehicle suspension would be attached. It also defines suspension properties such as radius, spring constant, damper stiffness, etc.

Suppose I correctly calculate the spring force magnitude (the classic `spring_force_magnitude = length_offset * spring_constant - spring_velocity * damper_stiffness`). Now I need to apply the force as a vector with the correct direction. Also, forget about other forces such as acceleration or steering, I'm just trying to model suspensions here.

Here is a diagram that allows to explain my issue. The car is inclined and the ground is a slope. Only 2 (or even 1) wheel is in contact with the ground. It's a side or front view (doesn't  matter) but suppose it's in 3D.
[image: Car diagram showing the world up, car up and hit normal vectors]

So there are the world up (global `Y`), the car (or wheel) up and the raycast hit (the ground) normal.

Most tutorials (like the popular [Very Very Valet video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdPYlj5uZeI)) use the car up vector. It seems logical since that's how the suspension spring is oriented. But when I use it and the car is inclined, it gets a force pushing it to the side. When I use the normal (like, I think, the [DigitalRune vehicle](https://digitalrune.github.io/DigitalRune-Documentation/html/143af493-329d-408f-975d-e63625646f2f.htm)) it seems to be too strong: the car jumps out because only 2 wheels are in contact. Should there be a factor that reduces the strength according to some sort of (which?) angle?

The question is: which direction? Car up, world up, ground normal, or a combination of those?

I use Rust with the Bevy engine and the bevy_xpbd physics engine but I don't mind any code that targets Unity, Godot or others.

Comment: Thinking of Newton may help here: which way is the road getting pushed? The push on the car has to be opposite that.

Comment: It's a good approach although all those angles confuse me. I'm not sure which way the ground is getting pushed.